# clear the screen in C without printing control characters

Tags: c, linux

Total noob to C here. Using Linux. I'm simply trying to clear the screen in a C program. I've tried every method I have found but with every one, I get the control sequence (I think that's what it's called) ^[[3J^[[H^[[2J printed at the beginning. The program outputs to the screen. I don't see them then but when I redirect the output to a file and then look at the file they are there. Any help?

Comment: Yes. the behavior is right. If you don't want to see in a file. You have to check if the program is running on the terminal and only then try to clear the screen.

Comment: See `isatty`(3)

Comment: The effect of control codes, such as the ANSI escape sequence you're trying to use, depends on the terminal you write them to.  Or for a software virtual terminal such as probably you are actually using, it depends on the software involved and its configuration.  More generally, controlling a display or other device is dependant on details of that device.  There are no general answers to how to perform most device-control operations in C, but you could consider engaging the ncurses library or a similar one that aims to provide the wanted abstraction layer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I remember reading something about the ncurses library but it was said if you use a function in it to clear the screen then it creates problems with the stdio input/output functions in your program. You'd have to convert everything to ncurses, so to speak.

Comment: Yes, that would be a cost to using ncurses.  Nothing is free, and you've made a bigger ask than I think you appreciate.

Comment: @JohnBollinger By this point I see that clearing the screen in C is not such a simple thing to do. :) You'd think it would be...

Comment: Well, clearing the screen is not a C specific problem. C is just one of many languages to use to reach the goal. A library like ncurses or any other is just that, a library implementing functions, realized in a specific language. So you might like to [edit] your question asking for the methods to clear a specific (or generally any?) screen without using control codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual sequence is `"\033[3J\033[H\033[2J"`, and contains three [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_codes#CSI_sequences):

- `"\033[3J"` = CSI 3 J: Clear terminal screen and delete everything in the scrollback buffer.  Specific to xterm-like terminals.
- `"\033[H"` = CSI H: Move cursor to top left corner.
- `"\033[2J"` = CSI 2 J: Clear terminal screen.

While these sequences work for most (if not all) current terminal emulators, the actual codes generated are from the [POSIX terminal interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_terminal_interface#Terminal_intelligence_and_capabilities) database for the current terminal.  So, it is not a good idea to hard-code the sequence, but use the terminal interface.

To use the terminal interface, you use [ncurses](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ncurses.3x.html).  You can use either the C library interface, or the command-line utilities ([`clear`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/clear.1.html) or [`reset`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/reset.1.html), the latter resetting the terminal properties back to normal/defaults, in case a previous program left them in an odd or unusable state).

Not wanting to use the terminal interface but wanting to clear the terminal is an odd combination; atypical in the Unix or POSIX environments.  You should reconsider why you want this.  For example, if it is just because you find it easier to read the output, just pipe the output through `less`, or run `clear ; ./yourprog` instead.

In the MS-DOS era, over two decades ago, the idiom `system("cls");` was common.  This executed an MS-DOS command, `cls`, that cleared the screen.  (If ANSI.SYS was loaded, then the ANSI escape sequence mentioned above would have worked just fine too.)

In Unix and POSIXy systems, you can use the [`isatty()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) function to test if a file descriptor refers to a terminal.  For maximum compatibility, you can use the macros `STDIN_FILENO`, `STDOUT_FILENO`, and `STDERR_FILENO` for the three standard file descriptors, although in Linux, they are always 0, 1, and 2, respectively.

So, technically, you could use for example

```
if (isatty(1))
    system("clear     2>/dev/null");
else
if (isatty(2))
    system("clear >&2 2>/dev/null");
```

to check if standard output or standard error is a terminal, and if one is, use the ncurses `clear` command-line command to clear it.  Per POSIX.1, `system()` uses a POSIX shell.  The above commands use POSIX shell redirection to ensure the output of the command goes to the desired descriptor, and that any error messages from the shell or the command (say, if it does not exist) is redirected to the null device, i.e. discarded.  This will therefore not output anything if both standard output and standard error are redirected to files or devices or anything not a terminal; it does not emit ANSI escape codes to redirected output.

Still, you should reconsider.  It is atypical to bake in such features to simple command-line commands; and it is trivial to make shell aliases or wrapper scripts that do the clearing before executing your actual command, so there is no need for baking it in.

Comment: I apologize for the delay in responding. Thank you Tuxlike for your detailed and helpful response. I finally got it working like I wanted to.